# Android Fragment onCreateView - inflating every time it's called?

Tags: android, fragment

I have been putting some debugging into my app to try to work out what is happening with the lifecycle.

I have some tabs and each tab content is a different fragment, each time a tab is changed onCreateView is called in the corresponding fragment.

In some of my onCreateViews I am currently mocking up some data and injecting table rows etc and then inflating the view every time. Like in the example below:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "******************* onCreateView() is being called in the Container Fragment *********************");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patient, container, false);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    //Set up tabs
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home_addresses").setIndicator("Home Addresses"), HomeAddressesFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("postal_addresses").setIndicator("Postal Addresses"), PostalAddressesFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("temp_addresses").setIndicator("Temporary Addresses"), TemporaryAddressesFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("email_other").setIndicator("Email / Other"), TemporaryAddressesFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tel_fax").setIndicator("Telephone & Fax"), TemporaryAddressesFragment.class, null);

    //Set to home addresses tab
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    tempAddressBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.temp_addr_tab_btn);
    tempAddressBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    tempAddressBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHandler(v);
        }
    });
    postalAddressBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postal_addr_tab_btn);
    postalAddressBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    postalAddressBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHandler(v);
        }
    });
    homeAddressBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_addr_tab_btn);
    homeAddressBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    homeAddressBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHandler(v);
        }
    });
    telFaxBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tel_fax_tab_btn);
    telFaxBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    telFaxBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHandler(v);
        }
    });
    emailOtherBtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.email_other_tab_btn);
    emailOtherBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    emailOtherBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHandler(v);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

My question is should I be doing this each time the onCreateView method is called? Is the view already cached somewhere?

I am seeing code in tutorials that looks a bit like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager_activity);
    if (savedInstance == null) {
        PagerFragment frag = PagerFragment.newInstance(buildPagerData());
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_fragments, frag, PAGER_TAG).commit();
    }
    findViewById(R.id.btnFragments).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeFragmentVisibility();
        }
    });
}
```

I know this Fragment in the example above extends from FragmentActivity and mine just extend from Fragment but it is using the fragment manager and checking if the state is null before deciding to instantiate a new fragment.

Edit: I am guessing as well that as this happens in onCreate and not onCreateView it happens less frequently?

I am wondering if this is something that I should be doing or if its ok to continue with the way I am going?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should manage your tabs from the parent `Activity`. Each `Fragment` should be responsible for one part of the UI.

Another advantage of that approach is that each `Fragment` layout will be a bit easier. And it will be easier to apply different containers if needed (e.g `ViewPager`).

Comment: This fragment has a set of horizontal tabs in it? So should also manage that set of tabs from the parent activity? The parent activity fragment does manage the vertical tabs which it seemed logical to do there.

Comment: What you're saying is that you have two sets of horizontal tabs in your view?

Comment: No I have a set of vertical tabs, each tab displays a fragment appropriate to the tab. On the first tab its content contains a set of horizontal tabs. The code I pasted into my example is for the horizontal tabs contained within the fragment.

Comment: Ok i get it now. I guess you can't really do much about it. `onCreateView` is called so often because along the way -when Fragment not shown- you could e. g. rotate your screen and have completely different layout for the landcape mode. I assume that the `FragmentManager` is pulling the shots on that one. You should inpect the place where you're actually showing you're `Fragment` with tabs, and check whether your creating a new `Fragment` instance every time you want to show it, and if yes try to first `findFragmentWithTag` before creating a new one.

Comment: Ok in that place I am also doing exactly the same thing as it is also a fragment, so in that place I should actually add a tag and then try to find an existing fragment with the tag. I shall try that now. Cheers.

Comment: That is created from a FragmentTabHost using: mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("content").setIndicator("content"), ContentFragment.class, null); so is it still appropriate to do that as I dont create the Fragment manually anywhere, a click on a tab creates it.